# Exclude column data from one table when restoring from a BACPAC file

Tags: sql-server, restore, bcp, bacpac

I have a `.bacpac` file from a large database.

The problem is it contains one table which has files stored as `varbinary` and is extremely large. This table is to large to restore locally.

I would like to restore the `.bacpac` file, but instruct it to ignore that `varbinary` column.

If this were RAW BCP, I know I could construct a format file for this table which simply skips the column (leaving it null, which would be fine). However, I cannot figure out how or where to apply a BCP command in the structure of the `.bacpac` file that would do that?

Is there a way to provide instruction to a `.bacpac` restore to ignore a single table column (like I could in BCP)? Or perhaps a way to edit the `.bacpac` file (zip) contents to insert an instruction for the BCP operation on this single table?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a direct option to selectively aware ignore specific columns during a bacpac restore.  2 options I can think of:

Option 1

- restore the db to a temporary db in azure or sql server
- use a script to create a new db without the varbinary column and copy the data from the temporary db to the new one.

  ```
  -- Create a new database
  CREATE DATABASE NewDatabase;
  GO

  -- Switch to the new database
  USE NewDatabase;
  GO

  -- Create the schema and table without the varbinary column
  CREATE SCHEMA YourSchema;
  GO

  CREATE TABLE YourSchema.YourTable (
      Column1 DataType1,
      Column2 DataType2,
      --...
      -- Exclude the varbinary column
      --...
      ColumnN DataTypeN
  );
  GO

  -- Insert data from the temporary database to the new one (excluding the varbinary column)
  INSERT INTO YourSchema.YourTable (
      Column1, Column2, /*...,*/ ColumnN
  )
  SELECT
      Column1, Column2, /*...,*/ ColumnN
  FROM
      TempDatabase.YourSchema.YourTable;
  GO
  ```

Option 2

- If it's too large to restore at all with the varbinary I'd try to create a copy of the original db without the varbinary and export the bacpac file